Add double quotes over comma or double quote
I have to make exports of multiple tables where i have to put double quotes over comma's and over a double quote. It has to be a CSV export and each column needs a double quote at the start and end as well. Is there a way to generate this in SQL? Each export contains several different columns per export.
Good to know, I'm using Management Studio 20. I saw in earlier versions the option "Quote strings containing list operators when saving .csv results", but that option is not available anymore.
I have now generated:
SELECT CONCAT('"', REPLACE(REPLACE([ProductDescriptionID], ',', '","'), '"','"""'), '"') as [ProductDescriptionID]
      ,CONCAT('"', REPLACE(REPLACE([Description], ',', '","'), '"','"""'), '"') as [Description]
      ,CONCAT('"', REPLACE(REPLACE([rowguid], ',', '","'), '"','"""'), '"') as [rowguid]
      ,CONCAT('"', REPLACE(REPLACE([ModifiedDate], ',', '","'), '"','"""'), '"') as [ModifiedDate]
      ,[Description]
  FROM [AdventureWorks2022].[Production].[ProductDescription]

But i have to repeat it for each table

Why not use a proper tool to export data? Powershell, SSIS or anything else can export and quote things properly. You can also i think use Export Data from SSMS and choose a Text qualifier to handle quotes properly. Btw, i'm pretty sure you don't need to escape commas?

Is is only needed for 1 time only, so I hope I can automate the scripting. No I need to add the commas instead of escaping them:)

Use DbaTools in Powershell Invoke-DbaQuery ..... | Export-Csv ...

I'm not really into Powershell. But if it is too difficult, that is also an answer, and I will do it manually

Did you look into Export Data wizard in SSMS?

*.csv/txt flat files always have host of problems where column delimiters, column separators, invisible characters like null terminators \0, special characters based on encoding, and line breaks are in the middle of the actual data. Or data elements are missing completely, i.e. column positions will vary.
The most reliable format for data feeds is XML enforced by an XSD. An XSD plays a role of a data contract between sender and receiver. It will guarantee proper data format/shape, data types, cardinality, encoding, and enforce data quality.

The CSV format does not require you to quote individual commas. It does require you to quote entire values if they contain commas or double-quotes, and to double-up and contained double-quotes. As mentioned above, it is best to use a tool (like PowerShell) that already has CSV support. However, it you insist, you should drop the comma-quoting and use something like CONCAT('"', REPLACE(value, '"','""'), '"'). Note this this will double-up any contained double-quotes, not triple them as in your original code. You can omit the quoting for some "safe" types like numbers, dates, and GUIDs.

If you are building one-off scripts, you can do some of the busy work with something like SELECT     TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME,     'CONCAT(''"'', REPLACE('         + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)         + ', ''"'',''""''), ''"'') AS '         + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)         + ',' AS Sql FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Production' AND TABLE_NAME = 'ProductDescription' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION.  See this db<>fiddle. You would still need to edit the results into full valid statements.

Thanks for the comments, these are very helpfull
